# Jquery cannot get latest value for session in my jsp page

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I am  using jquery ajax to send my request from client to server. I modified my codes according to @Samuel J Mathew suggestion.

```
    $('#create_kb_btn').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'create',
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#create_kb_form').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $('#query_form').removeClass('hidden');
                $('#query_res').removeClass('hidden');
                <%
                  Gson gson = new Gson();
                  String probs = gson.toJson(request.getSession().getAttribute("probs"));
                  String years = gson.toJson(request.getSession().getAttribute("years"));
                %>
                var years = JSON.parse("<%=years%>");
                var probs = JSON.parse("<%=probs%>");
                if (years == null || probs == null) {
                    alert('null');
                }
                updatePlot(years, probs);
                document.getElementById('query_div').scrollIntoView();
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error){
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    })
```

I'm creating a session in my `create` method as follows

```
req.getSession().setAttribute("probs", probs);
req.getSession().setAttribute("years", ec.getYears());
```

But somehow I always get null for years and probs. However, when I refresh the page manually, I can get the value. can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Analysis :-**

Based on my primary analysis on the code I found following issues in your code

On Page loading

```
<%
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   String probs = gson.toJson(request.getSession().getAttribute("probs"));
   String years = gson.toJson(request.getSession().getAttribute("years"));
%>
```

The values of probs and years will be null because you haven't created session at all and you are trying to create session on `create_kb_form` form submission.
Since you are using ajax post your page will not reloaded, so the values of

```
var years = JSON.parse("<%=years%>");
var probs = JSON.parse("<%=probs%>");
```

will always be null.

This is the reason why when you refresh the page you will find that it is working fine, because at that time you have session and all the values are populated correctly.

**Solution:-**

The solution for above problem is as follows

You need to create a ajax success handler method where you need to return the values of  probs and years from the create method.

and move

```
var years = JSON.parse(data).years;
var probs = JSON.parse(data).probs;
if (years == null || probs == null) {
    alert('null');
}
updatePlot(years, probs);
```

In short your ajax function look something like this

```
$('#create_kb_btn').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'create',
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#create_kb_form').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $('#query_form').removeClass('hidden');
                $('#query_res').removeClass('hidden');
                var years = data.years;
                var probs = data.probs;
                if (years == null || probs == null) {
                    alert('null');
                }
                updatePlot(years, probs);
                document.getElementById('query_div').scrollIntoView();
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error){
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    })
```

and you need to move

```
<%
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 String probs = gson.toJson(request.getSession().getAttribute("probs"));
 String years = gson.toJson(request.getSession().getAttribute("years"));
//Do json encode here and send as response here
%>
```

to your create method.
inside ajax success handler moreover you need consider the case when already session.

Comment: I've added the modified codes in the question description. Could you please take a look?

Comment: You are mistaken  i had edited the answer based on your code.